# Compiling GTK+ applications on windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, gtk, compilation

I was following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450445/installing-gtk-and-compiling-using-gcc-under-windows) in order to learn gtk but I cant seem to get it to compile.
I've downloaded the `GTK all in one bundle` and extracted it to `c:\gtk` (have also set bin as a path variable), but when I try `gcc foo.c %VAR%` it says `gcc: %VAR%: No such file or directory`, what am I missig here?.

this is my VAR.bat file

```
set VAR = -mms-bitfields -IC:/gtk/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/gtk/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/gtk/in
clude/atk-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include
/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtk/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/include/freety
pe2 -IC:/gtk/include/libpng14  -LC:/gtk/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -lat
k-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpan
go-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl

start cmd
```

and I have this in the same directory as foo.c

Comment: If you want just learn GTK and language is not important, then, may be, it will be easier to use `GTK--` (bindings for C++). It is very easy to use, and has good tutorials. Also, it can be used from Visual Studio very easily.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the spaces around the equals sign in the bat file:

```
C:\Users\unwind>set a = hello

C:\Users\unwind>echo %a%
%a%

C:\Users\unwind>set a=hello

C:\Users\unwind>echo %a%
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dev-C++ to compile GTK+ applications. Please follow this introduce 
http://users.libero.it/efa/gtkDev-C++En.html