# Not able to compile GTK3+ program on windows

Tags: c, windows, gtk3, pkg-config

I am using `MinGW` and I have set the path for the same in the `Environment Variables`. I have also set the path for `GTK` in the `Environment Variables`.

- MInGW has been set up successfully since I am able to use the `gcc` commands to compile regular C programs.
- Even `GTK` has been set up successfully (confirmed by entering `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` in cmd which prints out a list of variables and also ran a already compiled `GTK` application succesfully).

I have also set the path for `pkgconfig` in the `Environment Variables`.

- Variable Name-`PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and Value-`C:\gtk\lib\pkgconfig`

Even after the complete set up, there are some errors which occur when I try compiling a `GTK` program.

Command used:

> gcc hello.c -o hello 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0'

Note: I have used ` in the actual command and not '(used ' here to prevent highlighting).

Errors:

> pkg-config no such directory found. 
>   gtk+-3.0 no such directory found
>   unrecognized command line option --cflags unrecognized command line
>   option --labs

Tools I tried:

- Windows cmd
- MingW Shell
- MSYS2
- Cygwin Terminal (I haven't set up Cygwin path in the environment variables to prevent errors between Cygwin and MingW)

Can someone help me in figuring out what's the actual issue even after completing all the set up steps I mentioned above? Please help me!

Forums I already checked out:

- [Compiling and running GTK+ application on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325552/compiling-and-running-gtk-application-on-windows-7)
- http://www.tarnyko.net/repo/gtk3_build_system/tutorial/gtk3_tutorial.htm
  And more...But nothing has helped me so far!

Answer (score 0):

So I understand you have been using:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

You appear to be trying to be clever with pkg-config. Have you tried using `--libs` & `--cflags` separately?

e.g.:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o hello hello.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

For more info see [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html#id-1.2.3.5)

Comment: Personally,  I use the MinGW shell provided by MSYS2. Do you have `base-devel` installed [`pacman -S base-devel`] as well as `pkg-config`?

Comment: I have a folder named `Pkgconifg` in the Gtk Folder. I have installed the basic `GCC` requirements using Mingw. I am actually using Mingw. Isn't `base-devel` a default packge in Mingw? Can you provide some more info?