# How do i compile a glib application in windows withnout pkg-config?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, glib, pkg-config

I am trying to compile a glib application in windows 10, but i keep getting this error:

```
In file included from C:\Users\DamŔa\Desktop\C\glib-2.0/glibconfig.h:9,
                 from C:\Users\DamŔa\Desktop\C\glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from C:\Users\DamŔa\Desktop\C\glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from C:\Users\DamŔa\Desktop\C\glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from main.c:3:
C:\Users\DamŔa\Desktop\C\glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function '_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64':
C:\Users\DamŔa\Desktop\C\glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:818:31: error: static assertion failed: "Expression evaluates to false"
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) _Static_assert (expr, "Expression evaluates to false")
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\DamŔa\Desktop\C\glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:818:31: note: in definition of macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) _Static_assert (expr, "Expression evaluates to false")
```

while trying to compile it with this command:

```
gcc -I"C:\Users\Damča\Desktop\C\glib-2.0" main.c
```

I did some research and found out that it could be because i am not using pkg-config, but it doesn't work on windows, because it cant find the file `glib-2.0.pc`.

so, how can i compile it withnout pkg-config? or how do i make it work on windows?

Comment: Are you compiling targeting Windows (native compilation) or Linux (cross-compilation)?

Comment: @fpiette yes, i am targeting windows.

Comment: OK, then are you using [GTK for Windows](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows)?

Comment: @fpiette nope, but i will try it out. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @fpiette i tried executing the command `gcc main.c \`pkg-config glib-2.0 --cflags --libs glib-2.0\`` using MSYS, and got an error saying thet the package glib-2.0 was not found.

Comment: The GLib source code for Linux won't work for Windows. Use the [Windows version](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows) and try again.

Comment: It's possible that the difference between `C:\Users\DamŔa\Desktop` and `C:\Users\Damča\Desktop` will confuse some compilers.

Comment: @fpiette installing those packages and setting env. variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to the .pc file solved my problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @TimRandall it is possible but it didn't cause any problems yet, but changing it wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: Try out this website [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450445/installing-gtk-and-compiling-using-gcc-under-windows#:~:text=Whenever%20you%20want%20to%20compile%20something%20that%20uses,to%20compile%20from%20within%20a%20normal%20command%20prompt.)

Comment: @fpiette of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GLib source code for Linux won't work for Windows. Use the [Windows version](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows) and try again. Set the environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to the .pc file